# ERROR The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {...} was not handled by any navigator in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, aws-amplify

I have implemented AWS custom UI authenctication in my react native app and React navigation to navigate through the different screens.

While implementing the logical conditions to see if the "User is already logged in or not" I have assigned the screen "Home" for logged in user and screen 'Login' for not logged in user it's working fine and navigating as expected but the console is showing this error when clicking on login button.

```
 ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Home"} was not handled by any navigator.
```

Here is the Navigation code:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import {ActivityIndicator, Alert, View} from 'react-native';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from '../screens/RegisterScreen';
import ConfirmEmailScreen from '../screens/ConfirmEmailScreen';
import ForgotPassword from '../screens/ForgotPassword';
import NewPasswordScreen from '../screens/NewPasswordScreen';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import {Auth, Hub} from 'aws-amplify';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const Navigation = () => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

  //Checking if user is already logged in or not!
  const checkUser = async () => {
    try {
      const authUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({bypassCache: true});
      setUser(authUser);
    } catch(e) {
      setUser(null);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = data => {
      if (data.payload.event === 'signIn' || data.payload.event === 'signOut') {
        checkUser();
      }
    }
    Hub.listen('auth', listener);
    return () => Hub.remove('auth', listener);
  }, []);

  if (user === undefined) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator/>
      </View>
    );
  } 

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>

        {/*{If user is logged in navigate him to Homescreen else go throght the Screens based on the user selection */}
        {user ? (
        <Stack.Screen name='Home' component={HomeScreen}/>
        ) : (
        <>
        <Stack.Screen name='Login' component={LoginScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='Register' component={RegisterScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='ConfirmEmail' component={ConfirmEmailScreen}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='ForgotPassword' component={ForgotPassword}/>
        <Stack.Screen name='NewPassword' component={NewPasswordScreen}/>
        </>
        )}
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Here is the Login Screen:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, useWindowDimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard, Alert, KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import Logo  from '../../../assets/images/logo-main.png'
import CustomButton from '../../components/CustomButton/CustomButton';
import CustomInput from '../../components/CustomInput/CustomInput';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

import {Auth} from 'aws-amplify';
import {useForm} from 'react-hook-form';

const LoginScreen = () => {

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const {height} = useWindowDimensions();
    const {control, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}} = useForm();
    const navigation = useNavigation();

    const onLoginPressed =  async (data) => {
        if(loading) {
            return;
        }
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            await Auth.signIn(data.username, data.password);
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        } catch(e) {
            Alert.alert('Opps', e.message)
        }
        setLoading(false);
    };

    const onForgotPasswordPressed = () => {
        navigation.navigate('ForgotPassword');
    }

    const onRegisterPressed = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Register')
    }

  return (
   
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"} style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{flexGrow:1, justifyContent:'center'}} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
                <View style={styles.root}>
                    <Image source={Logo} style={[styles.logo, {height : height * 0.2}]} resizeMode={'contain'} />
        
                    <CustomInput icon='user' name='username' placeholder='Username' control={control} rules={{required: 'Username is required'}}  />
                    <CustomInput icon='lock' name='password' placeholder='Password' control={control} rules={{required: 'Password is required'}} secureTextEntry={true} />

                    <CustomButton text={loading ? 'Loading...' : 'Login Account'} onPress={handleSubmit(onLoginPressed)} />
                    <CustomButton text='Forgot Password?' onPress={onForgotPasswordPressed} type='TERTIARY' />
                    <CustomButton text="Don't have an account? Create one" onPress={onRegisterPressed} type='TERTIARY' />
                </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    root: {
        alignItems: 'center',
        padding: 20,
    },

    logo: {
        width: 200,
        maxWidth: 300,
        maxHeight: 300,
    },
});

export default LoginScreen;
```

Comment: can you share an expo snack? will checkthere

Comment: @GauravRoy I'd love to do that but not sure If I have to install aws in expo snack and put all the auth code of my project inside snack?

Comment: Can you show Login component?

Comment: @yousoumar I have updated the Login component code to the question please check.

Comment: Hi @ImranIrshad, did you check the response I pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

At the time you are calling `navigation.navigate('Home')` there is no screen called in `Home` in `Navigation` because of that ternary that checks whether there is a  `user` or not and renders conditionally your screens. That's why React Naviagation is not happy.

## Solution

React Navigation's [documention](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/) tell us that we shouldn't  *"manually navigate when conditionally rendering screens​"*. Means you should find a way to call `setUser(user)` in `Login` where `setUser` is the state setter from  `Navigation` component.

To do so we can use a `context` and for that change `Navigation` as follow (I added comments where I changed things):

```js
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, View } from "react-native";
import ConfirmEmailScreen from "../screens/ConfirmEmailScreen";
import ForgotPassword from "../screens/ForgotPassword";
import HomeScreen from "../screens/HomeScreen";
import LoginScreen from "../screens/LoginScreen";
import NewPasswordScreen from "../screens/NewPasswordScreen";
import RegisterScreen from "../screens/RegisterScreen";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/native-stack";

import { Auth, Hub } from "aws-amplify";
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

// Line I added
export const AuthContext = createContext(null);

const Navigation = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(undefined);

  //Checking if user is already logged in or not!
  const checkUser = async () => {
    try {
      const authUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({ bypassCache: true });
      setUser(authUser);
    } catch (e) {
      setUser(null);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkUser();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = (data) => {
      if (data.payload.event === "signIn" || data.payload.event === "signOut") {
        checkUser();
      }
    };
    Hub.listen("auth", listener);
    return () => Hub.remove("auth", listener);
  }, []);

  if (user === undefined) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
     // Wrapper I added
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          {/*{If user is logged in navigate him to Homescreen else go throght the Screens based on the user selection */}
          {user ? (
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Register" component={RegisterScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="ConfirmEmail" component={ConfirmEmailScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
              <Stack.Screen name="NewPassword" component={NewPasswordScreen} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default Navigation;
```

Consume `AuthContext` from `Navigation` in `Login` so you are able to call `setUser` after login, like below (I added comments where I changed thing):

```js
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import React, { useContext, useState } from "react";
import {
  Alert,
  Image,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  useWindowDimensions,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import Logo from "../../../assets/images/logo-main.png";
import CustomButton from "../../components/CustomButton/CustomButton";
import CustomInput from "../../components/CustomInput/CustomInput";

import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

// Line I added
import {AuthContext} from "./Navigation" // ⚠️ use the correct path

const LoginScreen = () => {
  // Line I added
  const { setUser } = useContext(AuthContext); 

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const { height } = useWindowDimensions();
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm();
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const onLoginPressed = async (data) => {
    if (loading) {
      return;
    }
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      const user = await Auth.signIn(data.username, data.password);
      // Line I added
      setUser(user);
    } catch (e) {
      Alert.alert("Opps", e.message);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  };

  const onForgotPasswordPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("ForgotPassword");
  };

  const onRegisterPressed = () => {
    navigation.navigate("Register");
  };

  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      >
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
          <View style={styles.root}>
            <Image
              source={Logo}
              style={[styles.logo, { height: height * 0.2 }]}
              resizeMode={"contain"}
            />

            <CustomInput
              icon="user"
              name="username"
              placeholder="Username"
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: "Username is required" }}
            />
            <CustomInput
              icon="lock"
              name="password"
              placeholder="Password"
              control={control}
              rules={{ required: "Password is required" }}
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />

            <CustomButton
              text={loading ? "Loading..." : "Login Account"}
              onPress={handleSubmit(onLoginPressed)}
            />
            <CustomButton
              text="Forgot Password?"
              onPress={onForgotPasswordPressed}
              type="TERTIARY"
            />
            <CustomButton
              text="Don't have an account? Create one"
              onPress={onRegisterPressed}
              type="TERTIARY"
            />
          </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  root: {
    alignItems: "center",
    padding: 20,
  },

  logo: {
    width: 200,
    maxWidth: 300,
    maxHeight: 300,
  },
});
```